# Custom classes templates under different folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, editor

I'm starting a project with .NET 8 and GraphQL (hot chocolate) and I use Visual Studio editor..

Every time I create a new mutation for GraphQL, I need to remember to create the class as sealed, and to add two attributes, for example:

```
[ExtendObjectType(typeof(GraphMutation))]
[Authorize]
public sealed class CreateMutation
{
    public async Task<TodoItemDto> CreateTodo(IMediator _mediator, CreateTodoItemCommand createTodoItem) =>
    await _mediator.Send(createTodoItem);
}
```

For the queries the template it's a little bit different, I need to extend another class, and let's say in other folders may be different..

I'd like to help myself to don't miss nothing, so I would like that all the files that will be created under a certain path eg: src/Web/GraphQL/Mutations will have a certain template (the one showed), then all the files that will be created under src/Web/GraphQL/Queries another template, and so on.. is it possible that kind of personalization on Visual Studio?

Not sure if it matters but it's .NET 8.

I know there is a main C# template class somewhere in the C/Programs/.. and I already edited it to have the class 'public' instead of 'internal', but I would like to know if it's possible to have different templates and all of them related just to that project, so that everyone which will clone the repository and will generate a new class under Mutations folders, the class will be generated like that!